# what is the recommended way to block the activity till the ACTIONs are unregistered

Tags: android, android-asynctask, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

In an activity, i have three broad cast receivers. and i have thrree Asynctasks as well. each AsyncTask when exeucted resuls in
triggerring a corresponding receiver. and in each Asynctask, I register the recievers in onpreExecute() and unregister it in onPostExecute() and oncancelled()

and I execute the Asynctasks from onStart(), and my shutdown module/function to cancel the AsyncTask is being called from onStop().

my problem is, when i press the back button to navigate back to the parent activity, the App goes into onPause, onstop, onDestroy. and by the time the activity goes 
in to onDestroy the some actions are NOT unregistered yet and that causes the App to crash.

what is the recommended way to wait till all the actions are unregistered then finish the activity?